# SQL: combining LIKE , Not LIKE , and IN , and then selecting the latest data

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have the below table:

table1:

```
filename    File_ID date    version
Broker1_file_12312  5093    20180108    1
Broker1_file_1sa3e_Renamed  3956    20180108    2
Broker2_file_d3223f 3109    20180108    1
Broker2_file_j3df   4526    20180108    2
Broker2_file_dj3498_interest    3574    20180108    3
Broker3_file_fj934f 5603    20180108    1
Broker3_file_jdf34f 5225    20180108    1
Broker3_file_K9d043 5926    20180108    1
Broker4_file_c34km  4865    20180108    1
Broker5_file_cf4k3  3212    20180108    1
```

I need to select the 'filename' and 'file_ID' in the output based on conditions:

1. filename should match from a list of patterns, but should not contain values from another list of patterns
2. version should be latest i.e max(version)
3. In case pattern don't match (error1) or there is more than 1 file (error2) , it could show that error.

The below code works, but I am not able to incorporate the "not like" functionality and , selecting the latest version

```
    SELECT t1.file_id, vals.val
    FROM
        table1 t1
        INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4'),('Broker'),('Broker5')) Vals(val) 
            ON  t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%'
```

I need an output such that it DOES NOT pick the file_ID where filename contains the string "Renamed" for Broker1, and "interest" for Broker2.
Also I need to select the latest version.

So from the above the need the output based on below comments:

```
filename    File_ID date    version Comment
Boker1_file_12312   4007    20180108    1   To be shown in output
Boker1_file_1sa3e_Renamed   5147    20180108    2   Not be shown in output
Boker2_file_d3223f  3496    20180108    1   Not be shown in output
Boker2_file_j3df    3880    20180108    2   To be shown in output
Boker2_file_dj3498_interest 5817    20180108    3   Not be shown in output
Boker3_file_fj934f  4541    20180108    1   Not be shown in output
Boker3_file_jdf34f  5818    20180108    2   Not be shown in output
Boker3_file_K9d043  4910    20180108    3   To be shown in output
Boker4_file_c34km   3101    20180108    1   Not be shown in output
Boker5_file_cf4k3   5209    20180108    1   Not be shown in output
```

Final Output:

```
val File_ID
Boker1  4007
Boker2  3880
Boker3  4910
Boker4  3101
Broker  error1
Broker5  error2
```

I am trying to add latest version from following code:

```
select file_id from table1 as t
where date = '20190108'
and filename like ('%Broker1%')
and t.version = (select max(version) from table1 as t2
where t2.date = t.date
and t2.filename like  t.filename
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter out recrods whose filename matches neither pattern `'%Broker1%Renamed%'` nor pattern `'Broker2%interest'`, you could just add another `JOIN` to your query.

```
SELECT vals.val broker_name, t1.file_id
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4')) Vals(val) 
        ON t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%' 
    INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1%Renamed'), ('Broker2%interest')) NotVals(val) 
        ON t1.filename NOT LIKE '%' + NotVals.val + '%'
```

**EDIT**

If you are looking, for each broker, for the `file_id` that has the highest version, this query, although quite ugly, should do the job :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT vals.val broker_name, t1.file_id, t1.version
    FROM
        table1 t1
        INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4')) Vals(val) 
            ON t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%' 
        INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1%Renamed'), ('Broker2%interest')) NotVals(val) 
            ON t1.filename NOT LIKE '%' + NotVals.val + '%' 
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    cte
    INNER JOIN (SELECT broker_name, MAX(version) version FROM cte GROUP BY broker_name) ctemax 
        ON ctemax.broker_name = cte.broker_name 
        AND ctemax.version = cte.version
```

Comment: it works but when I add selecting the latest version as well, then it fails.

Comment: @ArnaudKC : do you want the maximum of field `version` for the selected `file_id` (including records that were eliminated because they do not match your conditions) ?

Comment: Yes , that is what I want

Comment: It works but for case like Broker2, where there are two versions, I am still getting File_IDs for both the versions

Comment: @AnandKC : what do you want to do in this case ?

Comment: so in case of 2 versions,  File_ID of only the latest version should be shown. Note, File_ID would be different for the two files of same name if their version is different. @GMB

Comment: OK si basically all  want is the max version for each broker ?

Comment: yes, that's correct. File_ID for max version for each broker.

Comment: We could make this more generic... Is the broker name always at the beginning of the filename, like `'BrokerN_...'` ?

Comment: Broker name is not always beginning with 'BrokerN..'. In fact it is the actual broker name.

Comment: I ran your query, but somehow it is taking too much time to run...I may called for load on server, so I needed to stop it mid way. (other queries, that I mentioned in the request body above, hardly take ~0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

just insert one more inner join

```
SELECT t1.file_id, vals.val, max(version) over (partition by t1.file_id) version
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4')) Vals(val) 
        ON  t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%' 
    INNER jOIN (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4')) Vals2(val) 
        ON  t1.column1 NOT LIKE '%' + vals2.val + '%'
```

or with group by

```
SELECT t1.file_id, vals.val, max(version)
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4')) Vals(val) 
        ON  t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%' 
    INNER jOIN (VALUES ('Broker1'), ('Broker2'), ('Broker3'),('Broker4')) Vals2(val) 
        ON  t1.column1 NOT LIKE '%' + vals2.val + '%' 
group by t1.file_id, vals.val
```

Comment: it works but when I add selecting latest version as well, then it fails.